# What are the spinning circles that form the barrier that holds Zod and his minions called in the '78 Superman movie?

Tags: dc, superman-1978

What are the spinning circles that form the barrier that holds Zod and his minions called in the '78 Superman movie?

They kind of look like Hulu hoops circling in tandem.

Answer (score 3):

The [script](https://www.supermanhomepage.com/movies/superman_II_shoot.txt) describes them as "luminous Spinning Rings".

> **EFECTS:** The luminous Spinning Rings (c.f. Part I) descend and encircle the villainous trio, imprisoning them like a magical lasso in
>   perpetual motion.